# How to build an alphabetical tree from a list of words in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, tree

My problem is simple. I have a long list of words, e.g. abbey, abbot, abbr, abide.

I would like to build a tree as follows:

```
Level 0                             A
                                    | 
Level 1                             B
                                  /   \
Level 2                         B       I
                              / | \     |
Level 3                     E   O   R   D   
                            |   |       |
Level 4                     Y   T       E
```

Is there an easy way to parse the wordlist and create such a structure in R?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Sincerely,
Chris

Comment: Can you clarify what the output should be? A nested list? A directed graph from `igraph`? Or just the tree above printed to stdout? Or is there a tree data structure in R I am not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an `igraph`-based solution that labels each node of the graph with the partial word, so that terminal nodes are named with full words:

```
library(igraph)
library(stringr)

initgraph = function(){
    # create a graph with one empty-named node and no edges
    g=graph.empty(n=1)
    V(g)$name=""
    g
}


wordtree <- function(g=initgraph(),wordlist){
    for(word in wordlist){
        # turns "word" into c("w","wo","wor","word")
        subwords = str_sub(word, 1, 1:nchar(word))
        # make a graph long enough to hold all those sub-words plus start node
        subg = graph.lattice(length(subwords)+1,directed=TRUE)
        # set vertex nodes to start node plus sub-words
        V(subg)$name=c("",subwords)
        # merge *by name* into the existing graph
        g = graph.union(g, subg)
    }
    g
}
```

With that loaded,

```
g = wordtree(initgraph(), c("abbey","abbot","abbr","abide"))
plot(g)
```

gets

[image: word tree]

You can add words to an existing tree by passing it in as first parameter:

```
> g = wordtree(g,c("now","accept","answer","please"))
> plot(g)
```

The tree is always rooted at the node with name "" and all terminal nodes (those with no outgoing edges) have words. There's functions in `igraph` to pull those out if you need them. You haven't actually said what you want to do with this when you've done it... Or when **we've** done it for you :)

Note there is a nice layout for plotting trees which looks like your ascii example:

```
plot(g,layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
```

[image: tree layout]

Comment: Sorry, I initially thought this would do the job, but there is still the same issue as with flodel's solution, namely that if words in the list differ only by one final character, one will overshadow the other, e.g. "retrieve" and "retriever". Said differently, I would need to know when an intermediary node is also the end of ast word. I will update the question to reflect this issue.

Comment: Ok, thinking it through, using a marker for the end of the word would not create any conflict and would be easier than to think of another data structure. So your solution (as well as flodel's) will do the job. (To answer your question, a friend is working on Japanese linguistics and I am just trying to save her time by writing an R script that processes a large database of nouns and performs various analysis on it. One of the many issues is to study the frequency of coupling of kanjis in some subset of nouns, hence my question.)

Thanks a lot again for your help!

Comment: Good point! I think by adding a single end node that will work, but you then have a tree where all the leaves connect to the end node. I think two lines need editing...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that builds a nested list recursively, with characters as names:

```
x <- c("abb", "abbey", "abbot", "abbr", "abide")

char.tree <- function(words, end = NULL) {
   first <- substr(words, 1, 1)
   rest  <- substr(words, 2, nchar(words))
   zi    <- nchar(words) == 0L 
   c(list(end)[any(zi)],
     lapply(split(rest[!zi], first[!zi]), char.tree, end = end))
}

str(char.tree(x))
# List of 1
#  $ a:List of 1
#   ..$ b:List of 2
#   .. ..$ b:List of 4
#   .. .. ..$  : NULL
#   .. .. ..$ e:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ y:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. .. ..$ o:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ t:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. .. ..$ r:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. ..$ i:List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ d:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ e:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
```

Comment: Hi flodel! Thanks for the nice input. It is almost perfect. My description was not totally clear. Your solution fits well, but I would need to be able to store both "retrieve" and "retriever". If I am not mistaking, with your solution, "retrieve" would be overshadowed by "retriever" (because of the overwriting of the final NULL).

Comment: Sounds like you need a "terminal" marker so you have R-E-T-R-I-E-V-E then branching to "terminal" for RETRIEVE and -R-"terminal" for RETRIEVER.

Comment: That should be fixed now.

Comment: Dear flodel, thanks for taking time to answer my question. Your suggestion was simple and elegant, but I went with Spacedman's solution because it was more powerful. I wish I could mark your answer as useful, but I don't have the reputation points necessary for this.

Comment: This is an extremely elegant and versatile solution which I like very much and implement [in my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65819395/4139249). Would it be possible to somehow access the hierarchical level, as visualized in the OP's Question (`Level 0` to `Level 4`)